# Ignoring files and directories with .dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple `.dockerignore` file with the following:

```
.git/
.idea/
venv/
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file mounts the volume:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000",  "project.app:create_app()"]
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/frontend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Perhaps I don't understand the full syntax or intent of the `.dockerignore` file, but after running `docker-compose up --build`, `.git/`, `.idea/` and `venv/` end up in my container.

I've read up and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075434/how-to-ignore-files-in-docker) but it doesn't seem feasible that one cannot mount and prevent files and directories from landing in the container.

How do I prevent these directories from becoming available in the container?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.dockerignore` file will modify the context that is sent to the docker daemon to build the image. So the created image will not have these files inside unless you recreate them.

The volume mount is completely separate and a host volume mount, aka bind mount, will map the contents of the host directory directly into the container as is. This is a Linux OS level activity that doesn't follow `.dockerignore`.

You will need to exclude those files from the directory that you mount into the container, or not mount the volume into the container and rely on the image to take advantage of `.dockerignore`.