# Prevent the .env file being copied to a Docker container

Tags: docker, express, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

i'm newbie in Docker and i'm trying to make a "Starter-Boilerplate" with express and mongodb,
but i don't want the .env file in my docker image/containers, i've tried with .dockerignore file but the .env file still being copied inside the container in all docker-compose builds.

My .dockerignore file:

```
node_modules
.env
```

Link of the repo to reproduce the case:
https://github.com/josuerodcat90/expressjs-server-starter/tree/docker

Any idea or suggestion?, thanks in advance mates.

Comment: Is it in the image, or are you seeing it in the container when run with a volume mount?

Comment: is in the image i guess, because im seeing that using a bash `ls -a` on a mounted container.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Can you force the images to be rebuilt from scratch? I wonder if something is being maintained from the cache.

Comment: This is the link to the repo: https://github.com/josuerodcat90/expressjs-server-starter/tree/docker , clone it and create env file in the base folder to reproduce the case, thanks in advance.

Comment: your mounting a volume, which will cause it to look like its added the file

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sure, im using volumes, but how i can prevent the file got copied inside the image?, or any other suggestion to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50136016/596285

Comment: That's doesn't work for me, thanks, but I need a fully flow of archives between container and project folder, I guess, I need other way to do this, thanks.

Comment: i find a solution, or something like that haha, see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for these cases when you need to keep the docker volumes without troubles with your .env file and your docker-compose rules, see below:

First i declare 2 new variables in my .env file:

```
ENV=DOCKER //this can switch between DOCKER and LOCAL
DOCKER_PORT=3000 //for example
```

and then i've made a little change in my index.js and database.js files, when im working in `Docker` the enviroment vars must be different of my `Local` vars, and then the problem solves.

Thanks to all for your help and interest in my issue, sorry for my bad english haha.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.dockerignore` file if you don't already have one and add `**/*.env` inside it. This will prevent to copy any `.env` file from any folder.